# Python - Terminate a Process started in main

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing, attributeerror

I want to know how to start a process in main then terminate it in a def function. In my code, I have a process that runs an application of interest, then another process that runs a simple GUI using Tkinter which waits for a buton to be pressed. When this button is pressed, I want the processes to be killed. For instance:

```
def pro_a():
    #Runs the application

def pro_b():
    root.mainloop() # Runs the GUI

def buttonCallBack()
    #I want to terminate the processes here
    #I've tried doing: p1.terminate()

b = Button(frame, .........., command = buttonCallBack)
b.place(......)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=pro_b)
    p2 = Process(target=pro_a)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
```

When I try to do this, it gives me the error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'terminate'`

but when I try to terminate it in `main`, it works. But that's not what I want. To be clear, I need to start the processes in main, then end them once the button is pushed.

Comment: I don't see how you'd get the `AttributeError`. You should be getting a `NameError`, since `p1` is not defined anywhere that `buttonCallBack` can see it. Is there something missing from your example?

Comment: I don't think so. I've included every bit of relevant code. The weird thing is, if I put the same code I put in main, into the buttonCallBack function, then try to terminate...it works. It seems I have to start the process in the function to be able to end it in the function. But that's not what I want.

Comment: Do you ever reassign the value of `p1`?

Comment: I've tried assigning p1,p2 before terminating in the button function. I still get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't launch `pro_b()` in a subprocess, just call `pro_b()` directly. I think the `pro_b()` child process is ending up without a reference to the `pro_a()` child process. If you call `pro_b()` directly, then you will be killing the `pro_a()` child process from the parent process.